# What did 'regular' medieval people think about royalty?

Tags: middle-ages

During the Medieval times what was the general consensus of the common-people in regards to the King and his close associates?

From a number of documentaries i have watched recently it looks like the common people were charged high tax rates, and were generally treated badly by the land-owners/aristocrats/King.

Comment: @CGCampbell Is that any better?

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. Human nature was no different in the medieval era than it is now. If those having power over others were generally good and fair people, they would have been looked at favourably, if they were cruel, the reverse would be true.

Comment: @CanadianCoder Does that mean you think my question is too vague? How could i improve it?

Comment: Depending on the defintion that you choose the "middle-ages" can span a period of almost a thousand years. Assuming that we're talking about European history, it spans dozens of kingdoms, dukedoms and principalities and, therefore, hundreds of different rulers. Do you expect the "general consensus" to be the same for all of them?

Comment: Finally this video comes in handy! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtYU87QNjPw

Comment: @SJuan76 Is that a documentary?

Comment: More of a reenactement.

Comment: @CanadianCoder the issue is that most of the people would have little knowledge outside their town. For them, the "power" was whatever represented the local noble at the area; very exceptionally they would see their own lord. They basically knew nothing of what the king was doing, or why he was doing that.

Comment: Oh, and for the `comon people were [...] treated badly by the land-owner/aristocrats/King`, common people would have duties only to his feudal lord (which in turn would have loyalties to their lords, up to the King), so the King would not have had direct power over common people who were not directly his vassals.

Comment: I'm afraid the question is too broad to be meaningful.  Hundreds of countries, hundreds of years, perhaps a thousand monarchs and a million commoners.  Some they loved, some they hated. Isn't there a rhetorical fallacy when you overgeneralize?  Perhaps the best generalization is the Russian proverb, "God Bless the Czar and keep him far from me",

Comment: "  common people were charged high tax rates, and were generally treated badly by the land-owners/aristocrats/King." That's just as true today. That doesn't automatically make people hate the  government

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a vague question, but in general, kings were revered figures throughout history on average. Of course, it is popular now to criticize kings, accentuate their faults and scandals, and deprecate them as tyrants and monsters. But, in real actuality at the time kings were revered figures in their homelands for the most part.

Many peasants believed that the king could cure illnesses just by touching a person and it was common for people to bow or kneel at the sight of the king. For example, King Louis XVIII, who was enthroned after the Restoration, was an unpresumptuous man and he often used to just go strolling around in the gardens of Paris when he got old, and people would bow down and curtsy out of respect for him.

Even in periods of time when nobility was unpopular, in most cases the monarch was still held in awe and respect. For example, in Tudor England commoners were quite irritated by the "court" which were fantastically richer than the average person. So, they would sometimes throw mud or shit at them in the streets if they saw somebody in court dress. However, such treatment was usually reserved for random male courtiers. If the queen herself appeared on the street, everyone would bow.

Comment: Louis XVIII was in no way "medieval", and the Tudor period just barely at the beggining (1485 - 1603).

Comment: I gave those as modern examples that were analogous to medieval times.